# How to configure logging in Spring.NET using log4net?

Tags: log4net, spring.net, log4net-configuration

I would like use from Spring.NET Aspect library Logging aspect together with log4Net.
I found [this article](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/logging.html#logging-adapters-log4net) how to use log4Net with Common Logging API.

My test application is console and based on .NET 4.0 Client profile.

#### 1st Attempt

So I refer in my project these libraries:

- Spring.Core version 1.3.2.40943,  runtime v4.0.30319
- Spring.AOP version 1.3.2.40943, runtime v4.0.30319
- Common.Logging version: 1.2.0.0, runtime v1.0.3705

Assemblies above I have from  Program Files\Spring.NET 1.3.2\bin\net\4.0

- log4net version: 1.2.10.0, runtime v2.0.50727

I couldn’t find assembly Common.Logging.Log4Net.dll in *Program Files\Spring.NET 1.3.2\bin
\net\4.0* so I download this assembly [from SourceForge](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/downloads.html):

- Common.Logging.Log4Net version 2.0.0.0 runtime v2.0.50727

I configured logger in app.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="spring">
          <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
          <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      </sectionGroup>
      <sectionGroup name="common">
        <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
      </sectionGroup>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>

    <logger name="myLogger">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>

  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
    </objects>
  </spring>
</configuration>
```

and tried this:

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("myLogger");
log.Error("hello world");
```

I got this runtime error:

> {"Could not configure Common.Logging from configuration section
>   'common/logging'."}

Inner exception:

> {"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for
>   common/logging: Unable to create type
>   'Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter,
>   Common.Logging.Log4Net' (E:\C#
>   PROJECTS\STUDY\SPRING.NET\SpringNet.Aspects\LoggingWithLog4Net\bin\Debug\LoggingWithLog4Net.vshost.exe.Config
>   line 18)"}

StackTrace:

> at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[]
>   keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult,
>   Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   Common.Logging.ConfigurationReader.GetSection(String sectionName)
>   at Common.Logging.LogManager.BuildLoggerFactoryAdapter()

#### 2nd Attempt

I think problem must be in version of assembly Common.Logging.Log4Net *version 2.0.0.0 runtime v2.0.50727*. Because I used Common.Logging *version: 1.2.0.0, runtime v1.0.3705*.

So I changed Common.Logging version from 1.2.0.0 to 2.0.0.0. I used Common.Logging from [SourceForge](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/downloads.html).

And tested again. I got this error:

> Unable to create type
>   'Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter,
>   Common.Logging.Log4Net'

Inner exception:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging.Log4Net' or one of
>   its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"Common.Logging.Log4Net"}

StackTrace:

> at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName,
>   ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase)    at
>   Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler.ReadConfiguration(XmlNode
>   section) in
>   c:\CCNet\netcommon\trunk\modules\Common.Logging\src\Common\Common.Logging\Logging\ConfigurationSectionHandler.cs:line
>   130

#### 3rd and last attempt

Finally I found assembly Common.Logging.Log4Net version 1.2.0.2 in spring examples so I used it.

- Common.Logging.Log4Net version 1.2.0.2
- Common.Logging version 1.2.0.0
- log4Net 1.2.10.0

Tested and got again error:

> {"Could not configure Common.Logging from configuration section
>   'common/logging'."}

Inner exception:

> {"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for
>   common/logging: Unable to create type
>   'Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter,
>   Common.Logging.Log4Net' (E:\C#
>   PROJECTS\STUDY\SPRING.NET\SpringNet.Aspects\LoggingWithLog4Net\bin\Debug\LoggingWithLog4Net.vshost.exe.Config
>   line 18)"}

StackTrace:

> {"Unable to create type
>   'Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter,
>   Common.Logging.Log4Net'"}

I am really confuse what I do bad? Some problem with assemblies version?

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029460/spring-net-logging-example-using-aop ...

Comment: ... and the [aop quickstart](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html#aop-quickstart-basics) has a nice example on logging using Spring.NET AOP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Spring.NET 1.3.2 you should use:

- Common.Logging 2.0.0
- Common.Logging.Log4Net 2.0.0
- log4net 1.2.10

Make sure the last two `log4net` dll's are copied to the output directory. Since your code doesn't reference it directly, they might not be copied by Visual Studio.

Comment: working example: https://github.com/serra/stackoverflow/tree/master/spring-questions/q8167718ExceptionHandlerAdvice

Comment: @Marjin: Again, Thank you very much. You are right Common.Logging.Log4Net and log4net  was not in bin directory... I add reference on this dlls in VS but VS didnt copy these dlls to bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

Also, instead of

```
<resource uri="config://springs/objects"/>
```

Try

```
<resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
```

In your config file the sectionGroup name is "spring", NOT "springs".  I copied from yours to make mine work and got in the same problem.  Finally figured out why.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is:

- Common.Logging 2.1.1
- Common.Logging.Log4Net 2.1.1
- log4net 1.2.10

I recommend skipping Common.Logging 2.1.0 as it did throw this exception when reading perfectly valid app.config section:

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type 'System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection'."

Installing 2.1.1 fixed the problem.